# ¿Como hacer un programa que recorra la matriz con ciclos y que imprima solo negativos?

Tags: java, bucle-for, matriz

```
  String [][] valores = {{"0","-10","15","10","5"},
       {"5","20","-15","20","35"},
           {"-50","10","65","-45","30"}};
           
   for(int f = 0; f < valores.length; f++){
   for(int c = 0; c < valores[0].length; c++){          
    System.out.print("[" +f+ "][" +c+ "]");             
    System.out.println (valores[f][c]+" ");
    }   
    if (valores[f][c] < 0){
                 System.out.println("Valores Negativos: " +valores);
```

Tengo que hacer que el programa recorra la matriz con ciclos y imprimir en la pantalla solo números negativos y los indices que se encuentran en ellos.
El error que tengo es el IF el cual necesito el ciclo para solo los números negativos. Los números serian

```
    
{0,-10,15,10,5},
{5,10,-15,20,35},
{-50,10,65,-45,30}
```

Pantalla final:

```
[0][1] -10
[1][2] -15
[2][0] -50
[2][3] -45
```

Comment: Agrega el if dentro de tus ciclos.

Comment: ¿Dentro de los 2 FOR?

Comment: El código que pusiste no compila, asegúrate siempre de poner un [mcve]

Comment: Si el error esta solo en el IF, como lo puse en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto

```
String [][] valores = {{"0", "-10","15","10","5"},{"5","20","-15","20","35"},{"-50","10","65","-45","30"}};
public void recorrido() {   
    System.out.println("Valores Negativos: ");
    for(int i= 0; i< valores.length;i++) {
        for(int j= 0; j<valores[0].length;j++) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(valores[i][j]); // esto es para que cada valor pase a int
            if(num<0) {
                
                System.out.print("["+i+"]["+j+"]");
                System.out.println(num+" ");
            }
        }
    }
}       
}
```

Prueba hacerlo así, necesitas convertir los valores de String a int para que la operación aritmética, ósea la comparación del IF pueda funcionar correctamente

Comment: Excelente si me sirvió mucho gracias.

Comment: Un gusto, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código debería ir así

```
String [][] valores = {{"0","-10","15","10","5"},
       {"5","20","-15","20","35"},
           {"-50","10","65","-45","30"}};
   
   System.out.println("Valores Negativos: ");
   for(int f = 0; f < valores.length; f++){
   for(int c = 0; c < valores[0].length; c++){ 
       if (valores[f][c] < 0){         
            System.out.print("[" +f+ "][" +c+ "]");             
            System.out.println (valores[f][c]+" ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excelente gracias, aunque me sale error todavía en el IF. :(